# Bluetooth connections drops on Samsung Galaxy S 3

Tags: android

I have developed android java code for phone that receives data from a Bluetooth device at baud rate of 115200. The code works fine on Samsung Galaxy S plus and on HTC Sensation XE. But on Samsung Galaxy S3 the communication usually drops after some minutes and I have to reconnect Bluetooth. After experimenting with S3 and it appears that I can get the communication work perfectly in S3 too by first setting Bluetooth off on the phone, turning the phone off and on, and again setting Bluetooth on. Can anybody give a hint how can I get the communication work without booting the phone? Any help is appreciated.

Timo